# Interchange data between two row fields in the same row MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Factura` (
`IDFactura` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`TipoDevolucionActual` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
`TipoDevolucionAnterior` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`IDFactura`)
);
```

When trying to update a row in order to interchange `TipoDevolucionActual` value with `TipoDevolucionAnterior` value I get the same value in both fields.

I tried to do it like this:

```
update Factura SET 
TipoDevolucionAnterior=TipoDevolucionActual,
TipoDevolucionActual=TipoDevolucionAnterior WHERE IDFactura=1;
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
UPDATE Factura 
    SET TipoDevolucionActual = (@temp := TipoDevolucionActual),
        TipoDevolucionActual = TipoDevolucionAnterior,
       TipoDevolucionAnterior = @temp
    WHERE IDFactura = 1;
```